# Add schema to Search result page's body. Tried using is_search

Tags: functions, html

I am trying to add schema markup to search result page and I tried using the following code:-

```
function body_schema()
{
$schema = 'http://schema.org/';
if(is_search())
{
    $type = "SearchResultsPage";
} else {
    $type = 'Blog';
}
echo 'itemscope itemtype="' . $schema . $type . '"';
}
```

This doesn't seem to do it once I pass it to the body tag on my header. I tried searching for an answer all over and can't find an alternative solution to do it.

Comment: Is blog appearing? How are you actually using the `body_schema()` function?

Comment: Yes blog appears everywhere even on the search results page. And, this is the code I am using on header.php:-
`<body <?php body_class();?> <?php body_schema(); ?>>`

Comment: What's the search results page URL? Are you certain it's the standard WordPress search results? Not some plugin's custom search page?

Comment: the url is `/?query=searchquery`

Comment: Which is not WordPress' standard search. `is_search()` is for the `/?s=searchquery` URL, which is what the standard search form/widget leads to. If you're not going to use that `is_search()` isn't the right function. You'd need to see if whichever plugin is using that for search has a function, or just check `$_GET['query']` directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I am guessing Yoast SEO plugin is doing that.

Comment: I doubt it. Never has in my experience. Find out where the search form that leads to this is coming from. If it's part of your theme, the theme is responsible. If it's a widget that came with a plugin, the plugin is responsible.

Comment: You are right. I tried deactivating Yoast plugin, but the issue still persists.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I am sorry for the delay. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. The search form was using `<input name="query"` Fixed that and `is_search` is functioning properly. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, because this code is running in `functions.php` without any data being passed to it, it doesn't know what type of query is running, so it will always perform the `else` action.

You could take it out of `functions.php` and change your `header.php` to directly include the code:

```
<?php
// ... other header code
function body_schema()
{
$schema = 'http://schema.org/';
if(is_search())
{
    $type = "SearchResultsPage";
} else {
    $type = 'Blog';
}
echo 'itemscope itemtype="' . $schema . $type . '"';
} ?>
<body <?php body_class();?> <?php body_schema(); ?>>
```

This will work because when the code is running on the page itself, it knows whether the current query is a search query or not.

If you want to keep your function in `functions.php`, you will need to pass it a parameter from the header. For example, you could pass the `$query` var currently running in `header.php` and that way your function in `functions.php` knows what query you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried that and it still gives me blog for every page including the search results page.